# .htaccess AuthUserFile has no effect or is being ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

After hours of searching the web and trying dozens of unsuccessful solutions - here is my question.

I'm currently configuring a webserver on **RHEL 6.4** and **httpd 2.2.15** behind another RHEL 6.4 server using **squid 3.1.10** and **HTTPS only**. I'm also using `mod_rpaf` to simplify logging and identification of visitors behind the proxy.

My problem is to configure a *simple* password protected folder. When I try to access the folder, the password dialog pops up with the configured `AuthName`. So I know that the `.htaccess` is being parsed. But the dialog does not accept the correct credentials and gives me an **error 401**.

I messed around with:

- different permissions for `.htaccess`, `.htpasswd` and parent folders
- different **absolute** locations for the `.htpasswd`
- all activated Apache modules that are available on my system
- different encryption algorithms for `.htpasswd` (crypt, md5, sha, salted sha...)
- `AllowOverride All` on the protected and parent folder

But what I really do not understand that even if I put a *wrong* location for `AuthUserFile` there is no error message in Apaches `error_log` like the well known `Permission denied: Could not open password file`. Even on `LogLevel debug` Therefore I think that something is wrong with that Directive `AuthUserFile`.

I hope there is someone out there knowing better methods to identify the problem.

This is my simple .htaccess I'm using for testing:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Test123"
#AuthUserFile /var/www/test/.htpasswd
AuthUserFile /notexisting
Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it to work!
I tracked the error down to the squid reverse proxy by using lynx on my webserver and successfully accessing the protected folder from there.
With my new focus on squid I started googling again. Already the first link took me to the correct answer: **squid did not allow the apache to handle user authentication**.

**Resulution:**
Add `login=PASS` to the `cache_peer` command in your `squid.conf`